# Python RASA - Error "object() takes no parameters" while importing "from rasa_core.agent import Agent"

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Import command:

"from rasa_core.agent import Agent"

gives me the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-bdf78c35345b> in <module>()
      5 from rasa_core import training
      6 from rasa_core.actions import Action
----> 7 from rasa_core.agent import Agent
      8 from rasa_core.domain import Domain
      9 from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\agent.py in <module>()
     15 import rasa_core
     16 from rasa_core import training, constants
---> 17 from rasa_core.channels import UserMessage, OutputChannel, InputChannel
     18 from rasa_core.constants import DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT
     19 from rasa_core.dispatcher import Dispatcher

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\channels\__init__.py in <module>()
     15 from rasa_core.channels.botframework import BotFrameworkInput  # nopep8
     16 from rasa_core.channels.callback import CallbackInput  # nopep8
---> 17 from rasa_core.channels.console import CmdlineInput  # nopep8
     18 from rasa_core.channels.facebook import FacebookInput  # nopep8
     19 from rasa_core.channels.mattermost import MattermostInput  # nopep8

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\channels\console.py in <module>()
      1 # this builtin is needed so we can overwrite in test
----> 2 import questionary
      3 
      4 import json
      5 import requests

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\questionary\__init__.py in <module>()
      3 
      4 import questionary.version
----> 5 from questionary.form import Form
      6 from questionary.form import form
      7 from questionary.prompt import prompt

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\questionary\form.py in <module>()
      1 from collections import namedtuple
      2 
----> 3 from questionary.constants import DEFAULT_KBI_MESSAGE
      4 from questionary.question import Question
      5 

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\questionary\constants.py in <module>()
     38     ('selected', ''),  # style for a selected item of a checkbox
     39     ('separator', ''),  # separator in lists
---> 40     ('instruction', '')   # user instructions for select, rawselect, checkbox
     41 ])

TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

This error also reappears in some other Rasa imports.

Following are my versions:

Python - 3.6.6
rasa_core - 0.13.3
rasa_nlu- 0.14.4

There is a requirement [list](https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial/blob/master/Full%20Code%20%5BLatest%20release%20of%20Rasa%20NLU%20and%20Rasa%20Core%5D/requirements.txt) that is available online but the answer where it was posted resulted in error still not resolving.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced a similar issue.

Installing the following libraries with the version should resolve the error:

- python==3.6.7
- rasa_core==0.9.6
- rasa_nlu==0.14.4
- spacy==2.0.18
- pandas==0.22.0
- sklearn_crfsuite== 0.3.6

Cheers!

Edit: Make sure you create a new python environment while installing the above to avoid interdependency issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped. Just one small spacy error has come up related to the training data error **"Can't find model 'en'"**.  Any suggestions?